# Universal app version issue

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am creating universal app and I encountered following issue

> Argument type System.Uri[System.Runtime,Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] is not assignable to parameter type System.Uri[System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e89

I know error speaks for itself but It seems weird considering I downloaded only few packages like agilitypack etc. What may be the reason of such an issue and possible way out? 
**EDIT:** 
The problem is associated with Windows.Web.Http and System.Net.Http. When I use latter there is no error but unfortunately I need first one so as to notify UI about progress.

Comment: What are the steps and code can be used to repro the issue? Do you have any VS extension installed? Try disable extensions you added in VS and see what happens.

Comment: I pointed out reason of issue.

Comment: Are you using packages for Windows 10 Store apps, or for desktop CLR?

Comment: Windows 8 Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

I use "new System.Uri()" to build a uri for an image and Resharper highlights the syntax with the same error message you receive. If I build and run the project the uri works though.

Would be nice to get rid of the Resharper message though...